# Is there a way to use Chrome's phone interface on a Nexus 7 instead of the tablet interface?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I don't find the tab switching on Chrome for tablets easy. I know I can swipe from the sides to move between tabs, but I prefer the version optimized for smaller screens. Is there any way I can use the phone interface on my Nexus 7?

For comparison, here's Chrome on a Galaxy Note 2:

[image: Chrome on a Note 2]

And here's Chrome on a Nexus 7:

[image: Chrome on N7]

Comment: I had the same issue, but I didn't realize I could switch tabs by swiping the address bar until you mentioned it. Now all that's left is for a way to view all tabs like viewing recent apps.

Comment: You can do this with App Settings. See this other excellent answer for details. https://android.stackexchange.com/a/125852

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change this for just one app, but it can be changed globally by increasing the DPI value.

You will need to be rooted to change the DPI value. [This](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.marutian.dpichanger) app will change your device DPI.

You will have to play with different values, but take a nandroid first!

Edit: I played around with DPI values and 240 will force the phone ui mode for apps. Remember that this is global, and that it will make the app drawer look strange, as well as disabling the users feature.

Comment: well this works but its not optimal