# How to change the density (DPI) for specific applications?

Tags: applications, customization

How do I change DPI for applications only (different density for system and separate for each app)? I suppose there exist some specific part of code to change DPI value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) for that. It needs a rooted device with [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) installed and its module  be activated.

To change DPI for a specific app, launch App Settings → choose the app for DPI scaling (force-stop the app too) → switch the slider next to Settings → add DPI value and save.

See screenshots:

- first image -- before changing the DPI of the app
- last image -- after changing the DPI of the app

The rest is untouched, such as status bar or the keyboard app.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: This answer is so correct as long as you are in below Android 7. Exposed doesn't work in Nougat and there is no possibility to support. Does anyone know how to have per app custom DPI option in Nougat without Xposed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (paid; 7 day free trial) as well provided that OS is rooted.

- Profile: Application → select app fro DPI scaling
- Task: Action: Code → Run Shell

  - Command: `wm density <DPI>`

    `wm` implies Window Manager. Replace `<DPI>` with the DPI you want.
  - Check **Use Root**
- Exit task: Action: Code → Run Shell

  - Command: `wm density reset`
  - Check **Use Root**

That's it. Launch the app and the density of the whole system will change. Exit or switch the app and DPI would revert back to normal. The fluidity of the switch is not up to the level of App Settings, but it's acceptable.

Comment: This seems to make my device soft reboot. :/ The DPI appears to change but then it crashes and boots again.

Comment: Make a slight change in density and then proceed. It works well in stock Android 5.0.2, that's why I posted this answer.

Comment: I'm running CM12.1 on a Note 4. Tried only a small change but it's still crashing unfortunately. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: CM supports changing density from Settings app -> Display? Have you tried it? Do you face the same issue? And you're not using a nightly build, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Xposed Installer](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) + [GravityBOX](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox).

Comment: We're looking for detailed answers here. Please see [answer] and extend your answer into the required steps.

Comment: @Firelord You're looking for "lazy" answers, but the link you provided states this one is adequate. The only thing it was really missing is a link.